# Java Fractions, again

Tags: java, fractions, integer-division

Yesterday, I attempted to do this one way...today I am trying another and I am still stuck. I have to find a way of doing this using integer division and mod. Here is my code followed by the error messages.

```
public int evaluateFraction(int w, int n, int d)
    throws NumberFormatException
{
    whole = w;
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
    return portion2;
}
```

Tester

```
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter");

    portion2 = Integer.parseInt(input);`
```

error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 1/8"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at ClientCode.main(ClientCode.java:43)
```

Java Result: 1

What on earth am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Are you actually calling `evaluateFraction`? You need to rethink the approach a little as you should realize that you're accepting a string and returning a double from the fraction.

Comment: What is input, portion2? Please give as a sscce.

Comment: Just throwing in unrelated and unused code will just make a mess, not help.  You need to actually understand what you are doing.

Comment: I have to put together the value in dollars and in eighths. I used portion1 for dollars and portion2 for eighths.

Comment: I understand that I need to "understand", it's quite clear that I do not. Hence, the sole reason for which I am seeking help.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt` is able to parse only valid integer strings. If the input string contains anything other than digits then it will throw `NumberFormatException`.

You are trying to parse an expression `1 1/8`, which is not a valid integer string.

Comment: And to add, `evaluateFraction` is really not being used/usable here.

Comment: How should I go about this then? I've tried everything I know and nothing so far.

Comment: @AP you should better try to split your string using different arithemetic operators. You need to do this with all valid operators, get the operands and then work accordingly.

Comment: I'd be lying if I said I had any idea how to go about doing this. Would you mind helping me out a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

`"1 1/8"` is not a number. `1` and `8` are, whitespace and `/` are not. You need to parse such expression by hand.

Answer (score 0):

`1 1/8` is not an integer, `Integer.parseInt` can perform well in the only one case, if data is valid.

Don't know, what result you expect but you either need some other method or parse it yourself.